# group with a non cyclic proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I need to know which of the following group has a proper subgroup which is  NOT cyclic

$1. \mathbb{Z}_{15}\times \mathbb{Z}_{77}$

$2. S_3$

$3. (\mathbb{Z},+)$

$4.(\mathbb{Q},+)$

any finitely generated subgroup and also $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ of $4$ is cyclic so $4$ is out, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is proper cyclic subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$  so $3$ is also out. $S_3$ has proper subgroup $A_3$ of order $3$ so cyclic as it is prime order. so $2$ is also out.  so our answer is $1$, and $\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$is not cyclic but a proper subgroup of $1$, am I right?

Comment: But, as I know, $\mathbb Z_5\times\mathbb Z_7\cong\mathbb Z_{35}$ which is cyclic.

Comment: The direct product of two cyclic groups with coprime order is cyclic. $(\mathbb{Q},\,+)$ is the only candidate.

Comment: could any one give me an example of proper non cyclic subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ ?

Comment: @TaxiDriver: the rationals with denominator a power of $2$.

Comment: $S=\{ {a\over 2^k}:a\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: You have to find which of th given groups has a non-cyclic proper subgroup. Giving examples of cyclic subgroups in each case is of no help.

Comment: @TaxiDriver Yes. Although $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is more common to use (both give the same set/subgroup, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;\Bbb Z_n\times\Bbb Z_m\cong\Bbb Z_{mn}\;,\;\;\text{if}\;\;(m,n)=1\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\;\forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;\langle x\rangle\;\;\text{is a cyclic subgroup of}\;\;G\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\;(\Bbb Z,+)\;\;\text{is a cyclic group}\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\;(\Bbb Q,+)\;\;\text{ is $\bf{not}$ a cyclic group}\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

- the proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{77}$ have possible orders $3,5,15,11,7,33,55,165,21,35,105$ & all groups of orders $3,5,15,11,7,33,55,165,21,35,105$ are cyclic.So,all proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{77}$  are cyclic.So,it is not the answer.
- Every proper subgroup of $S_3$ is cyclic.So,it is not the answer.
- ($\mathbb Z$,+) is a cyclic group generated by $1$.And every proper subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.So,it is not the answer.
- what about $\left\{\frac{m}{2^n} : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$?